# Regex extract string, why my pattern don't works?

Tags: java, regex, file-io

I have a long string in this format (a long single line in file):

```
"1":"Aname","2":"AnotherName","3":"Sempronio"
```

I want to extract the number and the name and save them on a `Map`.

I tried this:

```
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    File file = new File("./SingleLineFileNames.txt");
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(\\d+)\":\"([\\w-.' ]+)\"");
        Matcher matcher;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            matcher = p.matcher(line);

            String name;
            int i = 1;
            while((name = matcher.group(i)) != null){ 
                // save in map
                i++;
            }

        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            br.close();
            fileReader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
```

result is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`

It's the right way to iterate on groups?

Where I wrong?

Comment: Are you working on JSON? Use a proper parser for that, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use hyphen inside `[]` then always place at the first or at the last.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(\\d+)\":\"([-\\w.' ]+)\"");
                                            ^ here
```

Also the way you are checking the group() is not correct. Check here:

```
while(matcher.find()){ 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Comment: It works both with
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(\\d+)\":\"([\\w-.' ]+)\"");` and with `Pattern.compile("\"(\\d+)\":\"([-\\w.' ]+)\"");`. Why, Sabuj, you say that hypher always place at the first or at the last?

Comment: For example this one `[a-z]` it means any character from `a` to `z`. So placing hyphen at the middle can change it's meaning. So its always a good practice to use it at start of end in the `[]`

Answer (score 1):

First split the String at `,` (`String#split`) and then split each resulting array element at `:` to get key and value. With input strings like these, I wonder what kind of masochism is on the developers using regex sledgehammers breaking these simple nuts..

Comment: I guess that regex is a most elegant way to parse this string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the broken square bracket construct `([\\w-.' ]+)` . For the name containing word characters only, it is enough to put `(\\w+)` there.

Comment: names substrings may contain `-`, ` ` and `.`